# Uploading and downloading blobs from GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Suppose i have upoaded 20 peoples images on GAE and if i want to get the image of a person, say Anand,how can i do it?I have read the documentation but could not find a way to distinguish between those images.Can i set names to those images because as far as know we can only upload images and get the blob keys.

Comment: save it as a blob property in a model?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model with a [BlobReferenceProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#BlobReferenceProperty) that refers to the blob key, and a TextProperty that identifies it.

Comment: I cant find BlobReferenceProperty in Java documentation even though it is in Python.Can you show me the link or any example?

Comment: I don't know much about how entity fields work in the Java API, but there is a reference on [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) to "blobstore key", which seems to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As you store images related to people, you probably have some kind of 'person' entity don't you ? All you have to do is to store the blob's key as property of the related 'person' entity. Then you can retrieve the image using this key.